# How to edit POST in resources.py with DJANGO-TASTYPIE

Tags: python, django, api, post, tastypie

I'm trying to calculate one of the fields in my django model based on data in a POST. For instance say, my Person model contains field such as: age, height, weight, gender, and BMI, and my `views.py` has a function which calculates BMI based on the other fields.

**Question**

How can I calculate BMI in `resources.py` the same it's calculated in views and add in that BMI value to the POST object?

For example, given this post, create a Person with the following **age**, **height**, **weight**, **gender** and also BMI calculated in the back end.

Normally, this post will create a person with BMI as empty.

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"age": "45", "height": "60, "weight": "130", "gender": "Female"}' http://localhost:8000/api/v1/person/
```

**Note**

This is just an example similar to my actual code. In my case, the field can't be easily calculated by the user in the same way BMI can.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for is to edit your ModelResource and return the BMI value after a POST. Try creating a resource like this:

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.utils import trailing_slash


class PersonResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'lol'
        allowed_methods = ['post']  # note that this resource just accept posts

    def base_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('bmi_api_function'), name="api_lol_api_function"),
        ]

    def bmi_api_function(self, request, **kwargs):
        deserialized = self.deserialize(
            request, request.body,
            format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json')
        )
        age = deserialized['age']  # all your post data will be at deserialized variable
        # you function
        bmi = 2 * age
        return self.create_response(request, {'bmi': bmi})
```

Hope it works for you